# Cronometro + Calculo em segundos

Tags: javascript, html, matemática

Tenho o código de um cronometro e gostaria da ajuda de vocês para implementar um calculo, vou tentar explicar o melhor possível.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do cronometro:

```js
var segundo = 0 + "0";
var minuto = 0 + "0";
var hora = 0 + "0";

function tempo() {
  if (segundo < 59) {
    segundo++
    if (segundo < 10) {
      segundo = "0" + segundo
    }
  } else
  if (segundo == 59 && minuto < 59) {
    segundo = 0 + "0";
    minuto++;
    if (minuto < 10) {
      minuto = "0" + minuto
    }
  }
  if (minuto == 59 && segundo == 59 && hora < 23) {
    segundo = 0 + "0";
    minuto = 0 + "0";
    hora++;
    if (hora < 10) {
      hora = "0" + hora
    }
  } else
  if (minuto == 59 && segundo == 59 && hora == 23) {
    segundo = 0 + "0";
    minuto = 0 + "0";
    hora = 0 + "0";
  }
  form.cronometro.value = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundo

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="cronometro" value="00:00:00" readonly="readonly" />
    <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="setInterval('tempo()',983);return false;">Iniciar Cronômetro</button>
  </form>



</body>

</html>
```

http://pastebin.com/5i5W9Sfx

Comment: Você precisa de ajuda em que parte ? Você não consegue implementar a conta é isso ?

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que o teu contador interno seja em segundos. Assim podes usar esse numero para os cálculos e podes sempre converter para formato de hh:mm:ss.

Uma sugestão seria assim:

```
var secs = 10760;
var hora = document.getElementById('cronometro')
var chamadas = document.getElementById('chamadas')
var segundos = document.getElementById('segundos')
var tma = document.getElementById('tma')
var desvio = document.getElementById('desvio')
setInterval(cronometro, 1000);


function cronometro() {
    secs++;
    hora.innerHTML = [
        secs / 60 / 60, // horas
        (secs / 60) % 60, // minutos
        secs % 60 // segundos
    ].map(Math.floor).map(
        s => (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s
    ).join(':');
    segundos.innerHTML = secs;
    var tmaVal = secs / parseInt(chamadas.value, 10);
    tma.innerHTML = tmaVal;
    desvio.innerHTML = (((tmaVal / Math.floor(tmaVal - 1)) - 1) * 100).toFixed(2);
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wyvtw2x0/

Comment: Sergio, não tenho como agradecer, é isso mesmo que estava tentando fazer a varias semanas, muito obrigado mesmo. Vou pedir mais um favor se não for muito incomodo, para que o calculo de desvio seja exato, eu tenho que fazer o seguinte calculo "o valor de TMA /214-1" , outro detalhe,tem como o resultado do desvio aparecer o símbolo %. Também notei que no internet explorer não roda o código somente no firefox. mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: parece que estou aprendendo, editei essa linha  >>> desvio.innerHTML = tmaVal / 214 - 1 .toFixed(2); <<< agora falta ajustar as casas decimais, pois esta retornando assim ex: 0.02691588785046717, e colocar o símbolo de %

Comment: @silvagno exato, o `.toFixed(2)` é para limitar a 2 casas decimais. Para juntar o simbolo `%` podes fazer `desvio.innerHTML = (tmaVal / 214 - 1).toFixed(2) + ' %';`

Comment: @silvagno ele calcula, mas talvez a ordem de grandeza esteja errada. Vê aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/uuqdz971/2/ Será que deve ser `x100`? Eu não sei que conta é essa para calcular o desvio mas os numeros estão lá e a conta acontece

Comment: @silvagno dá-me ideia que devias multiplicar por `100` assim: https://jsfiddle.net/uuqdz971/3/ não será isso?

Comment: @silvagno `0.01672897 x 100` dá 1,67...

Comment: Sergio, é isso mesmo, muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @silvagno ótimo! se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.

Comment: com certeza Sergio, mais uma vez obrigado mesmo :)

Comment: @silvagno: aqui podes ver como e porquê marcar como aceite: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/129

Answer (score 0):

Função para realizar o calculo

```
var calc_times = {
    sign: ''
    , value: []
    , convert: function(  data ){
        var c = String( data ).split(':').map(Number);
        var r = 0;
        if( c[0] == undefined ){
            c[0] = 0;
        }
        r += ( Math.abs(c[0]) * 60 * 60 ) ;
        if( c[1] == undefined ){
            c[1] = 0;
        }
        r += ( Math.abs(c[1]) * 60 ) ;
        if( c[2] == undefined ){
            c[2] = 0;
        }
        r += Math.abs(c[2]) ;
        if( String( data ).indexOf("-") == 0 ){
            r = r * ( -1 ) ;
        }
        calc_times.value.push( r );
    }
    , calc: function(){
        var sec = 0 ;
        calc_times.value.forEach(function(i,o){
            sec += i ;
        })
        if( sec < 0 ){
            calc_times.sign = "-" ;
        }
        return calc_times.sign + [
            Math.abs(sec) / 60 / 60, // horas
            (Math.abs(sec) / 60) % 60, // minutos
            Math.abs(sec) % 60 // segundos
        ].map(Math.floor).map(
            s => (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s
        ).join(':');
    }
};
```

informa os valores que quer calcular

```
calc_times.convert('-00:09:01');
calc_times.convert('00:00:03');
calc_times.convert('-00:00:01');
```

Chamada para resposta

```
calc_times.calc();
```